# jquery rotate plugin throwing uncaught exception

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, rotation, image-manipulation

I've got a problem when implementing the jquery rotate plugin.  I implement it like this:

```
var iDirection = 90;
var dImg = $("<img/>")
     .addClass('defect-image')
     .attr({src: $(this).attr('IMAGE_PATH')})
     .load(function(){
                //do stuff if img loads without errors
             })
             .error(function(){
                $(this).attr({src: 'img/missing.jpg' });
             })
             .rotate( iDirection )
             .appendTo( '.image-container' );
```

The error I'm getting is this:

```
 Error: uncaught exception: 
 [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 
 0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE) 
 [nsIDOMCanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage]"  nsresult: "0x80040111
 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"  
 location: "JS frame :: http://my.domain.com/js/jquery.rotate.js :: anonymous :: line 51"  data: no]
```

I need help deciphering this error.  I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong with this implementation. I've also tried (with no luck):

```
.rotate({angle: iDirection })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I'd put the call to ".rotate()" *inside* the "load" handler, or in a "success" handler:

```
var dImg = $("<img/>")
 .addClass('defect-image')
 .attr({src: $(this).attr('IMAGE_PATH')})
 .load(function(){
            //do stuff if img loads without errors
         })
 .success(function() { dImg.rotate(iDirection); })
```

*edit* — this seems to be a case of a buggy jQuery plugin ([this one](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/)).  You might want to dig through the "Issues" list for that project and see if one of the patched versions helps, or you could pick a different plugin.

Comment: @Pointy I've tried putting it inside the .load handler already and that gives me the same error.

Comment: Hmm.   Well that's the only thing I could think of; it's an internal error.  I wonder whether it'd make a difference to do it after you've added the element to the DOM too (after the "apendTo()" call)?

Comment: @Pointy - not to mention I can't seem to get .success to work. I though .success is only for ajax calls but I may be wrong...

Comment: @Point - I also tried adding it after the appendTo() call thinking the same thing you suggested but this did not fix the problem.

Comment: I *think* that with jQuery 1.5, all the ajax-y routines return a "promise" object with which you can add handlers like that.  I actually haven't coded with it very much.  What jQuery version are you using?

Comment: Oh also, what version of Firefox is this?  And what "rotate()" code are you using?

Comment: I'm using jquery 1.6 and firefox 3.6.16 and the rotate plugin is found here http://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/

Comment: OK cool - I'll try a jsfiddle just to see if I can reproduce it.

Comment: Well, [I get the same error](http://jsfiddle.net/Z4sLt/1/).  I suspect it's a bug being triggered by something that plugin does.

Comment: If you read through [the issues](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/issues/list) logged, you'll see that you're not the only one to find this problem.

Comment: @Pointy - i see, do you have any other plugin suggestions that would let me accomplish this same type of functionality?

Comment: I've never messed with anything like that, at least not seriously.  [Here is another plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/) and its examples at least seem to work in Firefox. (I'll try it in that jsfiddle I did.) (*edit* yup it works and the API is almost identical.)

Comment: @Pointy the new plugin you posted worked for me! thanks alot for your help